# Почему разная длина пароля?

Tags: php

Формирую пароль:

```
function createPassword ( $password_size ) {

    $nabor = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()+<>?/\{}[]~";
    $size_str = strlen( $nabor );
    $password = '';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $password_size; $i++ ) {
        $password .= $nabor[rand( 0, $size_str )];
    }
    return $password;
}
```

Прогоняю:

```
$p = '';
for ($i=10; $i>0; $i--) {
    $p = createPassword(10);
    echo "$p--" . strlen($p) . "<br>";
}
```

Вывод:

> 9+A77(!sPC--10
>   cIn+2L42o)--10
>   !iYVIjT(aVn5?28+9--9
>   Eu**2#*X*h--10
>   ))2L(]{i2--10
>   Tj#?vod*x@--10
>
>   LzZ2gTD?wb--10
>
>   UQD*yB{bdVm]to@x@--10
>   +F^lzEgw/u--10

---

> UPD Как сделать набор с спец символами?

сделал такой набор (работает верно):

```
$nabor = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

почему пароли разной длины?

Comment: думаю `rand( 0, $size_str-1 )`

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Mike, верно подмечено!

Comment: а мне еще нравится выводить пароль, а потом выводить длину но уже другого нового пароля :)

Comment: @teran это я сам нашел косяк, просто в вопросе забыл подправить)

Comment: Почему не используете str_random? там так же можно передать длину, и не нужен велосипед

Comment: @manowartop а где в `php` такая функция?

Comment: @doox911, пардон, издержки работы с laravel)))

Comment: давно уже пора удалить этот вопрос как бессмысленный

Comment: @Ипатьев почему он бессмысленный? Предложите ваш рабочий вариант с первоначальным набором символов (спецсимволами), или поясните почему это не будет работать.

Comment: потому что решение уже дали, и не раз. потому что этого вопроса в принципе не должно быть, поскольку РНР оборался на этот код ошибками - надо всего лишь прочитать и исправить. потому что "O6P~ni%(9B&NexPDa--10" - это бессмыслица. посчитайте на пальцах сколько символов в этой строке.

Comment: @Ипатьев 1. Решение не дали. 2. Не оборался. И это баг подправлен в ответе ниже, но он опять же не рабочий. 3. Я насчитал 1`O`2`6`3`P`4`~`5`n`6`i`7`%`8`(`9`9`10`B`11`&`12`N`13`e`14`x`15`P`16`D`17`a`--10` итого 17. И вопрос как такое могло получится?

Comment: 1. дали. 2. оборался. если его специально не заткнуть. комментарии под вопросом надо читать. 3. С приведенным здесь кодом - никак. это означает, что код не тот, а вопрос не имеет смысла

Comment: @Ипатьев 1. Ссылка на ответ? 2. Единственная ошибка которая выдавалась - `Notice: Uninitialized string offset:`. Вы отражение в мониторе увидали? 3. Что значит код не тот? Вы его запускали? Запускали приведённый в ответе код?

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: - это не "единственная ошибка", а прямое указание на проблему с этим кодом. которое надо прочесть и исправить. а не рассказывать сказки в комментариях

Comment: @Ипатьев так я ж сказал, что исправил.

Comment: @Ипатьев, проблема оказалась в отображении в браузере.

Comment: Признавайтесь, кто посчитал количество строк в выводе и увидел что их там не 10? :)

Comment: @teran не совсем понял (наверно туплю уже),  это вы про что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function createPassword ( $password_size ) 
{    
    $nabor = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()+<>?/\{}[]~";
    $size_str = strlen( $nabor );
    $password = '';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $password_size; $i++ ) {
        $password .= $nabor[rand( 0, $size_str - 1 )];
    }
    return $password;
}
```

Нумерация массивов начинается с нуля. Диапазон `rand` от нуля до размера строки, в случае когда он выдает число равное размеру строки - идет обращение к массиву `$nabor` с несуществующем индексом

---

*в дополнение к ответу: 
При просмотре результата генерации в браузере следует учитывать, что набор символов включает `<` и `>`, поэтому когда такие символы включались в генерируемую строку, браузер распознавал в них неизвестный тэг и скрывал все, что между ними находилось*

Comment: чего минусуете-то, данный код все верно генерит, по 10 символов.

Comment: https://ideone.com/41cEN5

Comment: да хоть 200, обновил сниппет. какая версия пхп у вас, в какой кодировке файл?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91069/discussion-between-doox911-and-teran).

Comment: @teran, минусуют не от большого ума. Код рабочий, заходил по ссылке - всё ок. Так же отличное замечание о тегах `<` и `>`.